# MongoDB Stats Count Different from Number of Documents

Tags: java, mongodb

Robomongo shows that I have 50 documents in my database's collection (which is true), and yet, the console output from the following says otherwise; `count()` returns 4494 and so does `stats()`. This is causing my cursor to erroneously iterate through the collection repeatedly instead of just once.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_PORT);

DB db = mongoClient.getDB(DATABASE_NAME);

DBCollection documentCollection = db.getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME);

DBCursor cursor = documentCollection.find();

System.out.println("Number of documents in collection: " + cursor.count());
```

Please help! Sincerely confused.

P.S. I have used `validate()` to confirm that all documents in the collection are valid. Also, `documentCollection.getCount()` returns the same value of 4494.

Comment: Robomongo paginates results, 50 documents per page by default. What it returns when you execute `db.COLLECTION_NAME.count()` ?

Comment: @AlexBlex Yes, thank you, I just realized that as well. Do add your comment as an answer, :), so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robomongo paginates results, 50 documents per page by default.
`db.COLLECTION_NAME.count()` returns total number of documents in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection;
collection.count();
```